# fan noise in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: fan, noise

I have installed ubuntu 12.01 on my laptop Dell Inspiron E1705. The fan is running continuously and is quite noise. Is there any way to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'd suggest you give [this question on controlling fan speed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) a look, that should solve your problem. Otherwise check [my answer to another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/197440/overheating-in-hp-pavillion-dm4-2102eo-laptop/210138#210138) which suggests the Jupiter applet which reduces CPU usage when required and therefore the amount the fan has to run. If the problem persists edit your question mentioning that those didn't work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Install fancontrol and lm-sensors:

```
sudo apt-get install fancontrol lm-sensors
```

Start lm-sensors:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Answer 'yes' to all questions. Then start this: `/etc/init.d/module-init-tools start`
Now you could see some info 'bout your system:

```
sudo sensors
```

Build config-files:

```
touch /etc/fancontrol
chmod 666 /etc/fancontrol
```

Run the configuration utility:

```
sudo pwmconfig
```

Now tune pwm of ur fan and save changes. Run fancontrol:

```
/etc/init.d/fancontrol start
```

Enjoy.